# JNI callback invocation when running multithreaded

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, driver, libusb

Currently I try to get the [stettbacher](http://www.open-cam.ch/en) O-3000 cameras to get running with my Java client.
For this I use JNI to invoke the driver functions. Everything works as expected.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

*(Java)*

```
...
static {
    System.loadLibrary("o3000jni");
}
...

private Camo3000JNI jni;

private Model model;
...
Model model = Model();
Camo3000JNI jni = new Camo3000JNI(model, 0));
jni.init();
...
jni.start();
...
```

*(JNI class taken from the official demo (little bit modified))*

```
public class Camo3000JNI implements Runnable {

    private boolean debug               = true;
    private CameraDevsInterface camIface; //Model is implementing this
    private boolean keepRunning         = true;
    private final static int E_SUCCESS  = 0, E_NOCALLBACK = 1, E_NOMEM = 2, E_NODEV = 3, E_OTHER =4;
    private int w                       = 1280; private int h = 960;
    private int[] video_data_array      = new int[w*h];
    private Thread thd_cam;
    private int session                 = -1;
    private int cameraNumber;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Camo3000JNI(CameraDevsInterface camIface, int cameraNumber) {
        this.camIface       = camIface;
        thd_cam             = new Thread(this);
        this.cameraNumber   = cameraNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Start blocking thread
     */
    public void startThread() {
        thd_cam.start();
    }

    public int init(){

        System.out.println("Initializing session for camera: " + cameraNumber);
        session = initCamDriver(0x0483,0xA098, video_data_array);

        if(0 >= session)
            throw new RuntimeException("Session for camera " + cameraNumber + " could not be initialized!");

        camIface.setOnOffStatus(E_SUCCESS);
        // warning: camera not connected, just initialized, kernel will queue any pending XML messages from host to device

        return session;

    }


    // callbacks:
    /**
     * Handling receiving video data
     */
    public void video_handler(int width, int height, int format){
        camIface.streamVid(video_data_array, width, height, format);
    }
    /**
     * Handling receiving xml messages
     */
    public void xml_handler(String buf, int len){
        if (debug){System.out.println("XXXXXXX IN: " + buf);}
        camIface.setXMLresp(buf);
    }

    /**
     * Handling receiving log messages
     */
    public void log_handler(String log){
        log = log.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
        camIface.setLogresp(log);
    }
    // callbacks: end


    // native calls
    public native int sendXMLcmd(int session, String xmlCmd);
    public native int initCamDriver(int vid, int pid, int[] video_data_array);
    public native void stopCamDriver(int session);
    public native int connectCamDriver(int session, int cameraNumber);
    public native int availableCameraCount(int session);
    // native calls: end

    public int getNumberOfCams(){
        return availableCameraCount(session);
    }

    public int sendXMLcmd(String xml){
        return sendXMLcmd(session, xml);
    }

    /**
     * Runnable method of this thread
     */
    public void run() {

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        while (keepRunning) {

            if (session != E_SUCCESS){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Sleep not successful in jni run: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (connectCamDriver(session, cameraNumber) != E_SUCCESS){
                System.out.println("Not connected!!!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop thread is never called out of camera context
     */
    public synchronized void stopo3000Cam(){

        keepRunning = false;

        stopCamDriver(session);

    }
}
```

*(interface the model is implementing)*

```
/**
 * Interface for Camera Implementation
 */
public interface CameraDevsInterface {
    public void streamVid(int[] video_data, int width, int height, int format);
    public void setXMLresp(String xml_response);
    public void setLogresp(String log_response);
    public void setOnOffStatus(int ret);
}
```

Now I have a method to take a snapshot:

```
    File file = new File("snapshot.png");

    jni.sendXMLcmd("<camera><start></start></camera>");


    if(model.getOnOffStatus() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Cam connected!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not connected!");
    }


    jni.sendXMLcmd("<camera><stream></stream></camera>");
    jni.sendXMLcmd("<camera><snapshot></snapshot></camera>");

    jni.video_handler(1280, 960, 12);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ImageIO.write(toBufferedImage(model.getImage()), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jni.sendXMLcmd("<camera><stop></stop></camera>");
```

Everything of the above works but only if I run it in its own process. I.e. when I try to start multiple threads (jni-objects) I can communicate with the driver (I get the correct number of cameras f.e.) but if I try to take a snapshot I get only a black image back.
My thoughts are that there is something with the callbacks which I have to implement another way for multi-threading (for now I have only little experience with JNI thought).

Maybe someone can help me to understand what the problem could be or how I have to refactor the code.

[Sources & additional info]

[driver](https://github.com/StettbacherSignalProcessing/O-3000/blob/master/driver/src/o3000/o3000.c)
*on Windows one gets all the sources after installing the .exe provided on official sources.

*(o3000_jni.h)*

```
/**
 *  Java Demo Software for the o3000-series: SSP_StreamingCamera
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 2013 by Stettbacher Signal Processing
...cut
 **/

/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class o3000_Camo3000JNI */

#ifndef _Included_o3000_Camo3000JNI
#define _Included_o3000_Camo3000JNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_SUCCESS
#define o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_SUCCESS 0L
#undef o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NOCALLBACK
#define o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NOCALLBACK 1L
#undef o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NOMEM
#define o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NOMEM 2L
#undef o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NODEV
#define o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_NODEV 3L
#undef o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_OTHER
#define o3000_Camo3000JNI_E_OTHER 4L
/*
 * Class:     o3000_Camo3000JNI
 * Method:    sendXMLcmd
 * Signature: (ILjava/lang/String;)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_sendXMLcmd
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     o3000_Camo3000JNI
 * Method:    initCamDriver
 * Signature: (II[I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_initCamDriver
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint, jintArray);

/*
 * Class:     o3000_Camo3000JNI
 * Method:    stopCamDriver
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_stopCamDriver
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     o3000_Camo3000JNI
 * Method:    connectCamDriver
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_connectCamDriver
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

/*
 * Class:     o3000_Camo3000JNI
 * Method:    availableCameraCount
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_availableCameraCount
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

(o3000_jni.c)

```
/* 
 ...cut
 */
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <o3000/o3000.h>
#include <o3000/color_pipe.h>
#include <o3000/o3000_jni.h>


#define FALSE           0
#define TRUE            1

#define IMAGE_FRAME_WIDTH       1280            // maximum image width in pixels
#define IMAGE_FRAME_HEIGHT      960             // maximum image height in pixels

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global references for callbacks
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
jmethodID video_handler_id;
jmethodID xml_handler_id;
jmethodID log_handler_id;

JNIEnv *env_cached;
jobject obj_cached;
jobject viddata_chached;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// end: Global references for callbacks
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// prototypes (not in *.h file because *.h file is automatically generated
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// end prototypes
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

static int flag_connection = FALSE;

static char xml_msg_default[] = {"<camera><stop></stop></camera>"};

static struct color_pipe_t *color_pipe;


/**
 * \brief   XML handler
 *
 * Passes a string (xml answer: callback) to to java application
 *
 * \param   *buf    Pointer to string
 * \param   len     String's length
 */
static __stdcall void xml_handling(int id, char* buf, int len) {
    jstring jstr;

    /* Create a new string and overwrite the instance field */
    jstr = (*env_cached)->NewStringUTF(env_cached, buf);

    if (jstr == NULL) {
        return; /* out of memory */
    }

    (*env_cached)->CallVoidMethod(env_cached,obj_cached,xml_handler_id, jstr, len); // calls Java method "xml_handler"
}

/**
 * Wrapper function to copy pipelinde image to java memory space.
 * The pixel alignment of the input image (pipelined image) depends on the bit-depth and 
 * color/mono type. The input image is copied to the a jint-array located at JVM memory space.
 * 
 * @param img_out Pointer to java memory space. Pipelined image is saved here.
 * @param img_in Pointer to pipelined image.
 * @param is_color not 0 if color, 0 if monochrome
 * @param height image height in number of pixels
 * @param width image width in number of pixels
 * @param bit_channel bits per color channel
 */
static void pipe2jint(jint *img_out, void *__restrict__ img_in, const int is_color, const int height, const int width, const int bit_channel) {

    int index, y, x, pixel, red, green, blue;
    uint8_t *img8;
    uint16_t *img16;


    if(is_color) {
        if(bit_channel == 8) {
            /*
             * Color image, 8 bit-per-pixel
             */
            index = 0;
            img8 = (uint8_t *)img_in;
            for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    red = *img8;
                    img8++;
                    green = *img8;
                    img8++;
                    blue = *img8;
                    img8++;

                    img_out[index] = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(bit_channel == 12) {
            /*
             * Color image, 12 bit-per-pixel
             */
            index = 0;
            img16 = (uint16_t *)img_in;
            for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    red = (*img16 >> 4);
                    img16++;
                    green = (*img16 >> 4);
                    img16++;
                    blue = (*img16 >> 4);
                    img16++;

                    img_out[index] = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
                    index++;
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            printf("%s: Can't display image with %d bits per color channel. Do implement it here!\n", __func__, bit_channel);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(bit_channel == 8) {
            /*
             * Monochrome image, 8 bit-per-pixel
             */
            index = 0;
            img8 = (uint8_t *)img_in;
            for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    pixel = *img8;
                    img8++;
                    img_out[index] = (pixel << 16) | (pixel << 8) | pixel;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(bit_channel == 12) {
            /*
             * Monochrome image, 12 bit-per-pixel
             */
            index = 0;
            img16 = (uint16_t *)img_in;
            for(y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    pixel = *img16;
                    pixel = (pixel >> 4) & 0xff;    // cut off 4 LSBs because the monitor can't display more than 8 bits per color
                    img16++;
                    img_out[index] = (pixel << 16) | (pixel << 8) | pixel;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("%s: Can't display image with %d bits per color channel. Do implement it here!\n", __func__, bit_channel);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * \brief   Video handler
 *
 * Passes video data (callback) to to java application
 *
 * \param   *buf        Pointer to video data
 * \param   img_header  Information about image data
 */
static __stdcall void video_handling(int id, unsigned char* buf, struct img_header_t* img_header) {

    jint *img;   // image array located into java virtual machine memory space

    // get Java Array 
    img = (*env_cached)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(env_cached,viddata_chached,0);
    if (img == NULL){
        return;
    }

    /*
     * process image at color pipe and copy image to JVM memory space
     */
    color_pipe_process(color_pipe, buf, img_header);
    pipe2jint(img, color_pipe->img_out, color_pipe->is_color, color_pipe->height, color_pipe->width, color_pipe->bit_channel);


    (*env_cached)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(   env_cached,
                                                    viddata_chached,
                                                    img,
                                                    0);

    // calls java methid "video_handler"
    (*env_cached)->CallVoidMethod(  env_cached,
                                    obj_cached,
                                    video_handler_id,
                                    color_pipe->width,
                                    color_pipe->height,
                                    img_header->format);
}

/**
 * \brief   Log handler
 *
 * Gives logs to the java interface
 * 
 * \param   *msg        Pointer to log message
 */
static __stdcall void log_handling(int id, char* msg) {
    jstring jstr;

    if (env_cached == NULL){
        return;
    }

    /* Create a new string and overwrite the instance field */
    jstr = (*env_cached)->NewStringUTF(env_cached, msg);

    if (jstr == NULL) {
        return; /* out of memory */
    }

    (*env_cached)->CallVoidMethod(env_cached,obj_cached,log_handler_id, jstr); // calls Java method "log_handler"

// printf("LOG: %s ------ %s\n", __func__, msg);
}

/**
 * \brief   Java native call sendXMLcmd(String xmlCmd)
 * 
 * Sends the xml String passed from java method to the connected camera
 *
 * \param   *env    Pointer to log java env (JVM), automatically generated by jni
 * \param   obj     Pointer to log java object, automaticall generated by jni
 * \param   session Session to use
 * \param   jstr    Message to send
 * 
 * \return  ret     succes state
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_sendXMLcmd(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint session, jstring jstr){
    const char *str;
    int len,  ret;

    // get message's properties
    if(flag_connection == FALSE) {
        printf("%s: no connection\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }
    str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, NULL);
    if (str == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    len = (*env)->GetStringUTFLength(env, jstr);
    if (str == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    // libo3000 function call
    ret = o3000_send_xml(session, str, len);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr, str); 

    return ((jint)ret);
}

/**
 * \brief   Java native call initCamDriver(int vid, int pid, int[] video_data_array);
 * 
 * Initialises the camera with all necessary information.
 *
 * \param   *env                Pointer to log java env (JVM), automatically generated by jni
 * \param   obj                 Pointer to log java object, automaticall generated by jni
 * \param   vid                 Vendor ID (USB purpose)
 * \param   pid                 Product ID (USB purpose)
 * \param   video_data_array    Reference to java array for video handling function (callback address)
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_initCamDriver(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint vid, jint pid, jintArray viddata){

    int cam_session, num_camera = -1;

    env_cached = NULL;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);

    // make object globally available
    obj_cached = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
    if (obj_cached == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    // make array globally available
    viddata_chached = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,viddata);
    if (viddata_chached == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    // look for "xml_handler" Java method
    jmethodID xmlhand = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "xml_handler", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V");
    if (xmlhand == NULL){
        return -1; /* Method not found */
    }
    xml_handler_id = xmlhand;

    // look for "video_handler" Java method
    jmethodID vidhand = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "video_handler", "(III)V");
    if (vidhand == NULL){
        return -1; /* Method not found */
    }
    video_handler_id = vidhand;

    // look for "log_handler" Java method
    jmethodID loghand = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "log_handler", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (loghand == NULL){
        return -1; /* Method not found */
    }
    log_handler_id = loghand;

    // setup camera session
    cam_session = o3000_init(vid, pid, 1024*1024*4, xml_handling, video_handling, log_handling, O3000_LOG_INFO);
    if(cam_session < 0) {
        printf("%s: Error opening new camera session (code %d)\n", __func__, cam_session);
        return -1;
    }

    num_camera = o3000_device_discovery(cam_session);
    if(num_camera < 0) {
        printf("%s: device discovery error (code %d)\n", __func__, num_camera);
        o3000_exit(cam_session);
        cam_session = -1;
        return -1;
    }

    if(num_camera == 0) {
//      printf("%s: no camera connected to the system\n", __func__);
        o3000_exit(cam_session);
        cam_session = -1;
        return -1;
    }
    flag_connection = TRUE;
    return cam_session;

}

/**
 * \brief   Java native call availableCameraCount(int session);
 * 
 * Return the number of connected cameras.
 *
 * \param   *env    Pointer to log java env (JVM), automatically generated by jni
 * \param   obj     Pointer to log java object, automaticall generated by jni
 * \param   session Session to use
 * 
 * \return  ret     number of connected cameras (< 0: device discovery error; 0: no camera connected to the system; > 0: number of connected cameras)
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_availableCameraCount(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint session){
    return o3000_device_discovery(session);
}

/**
 * \brief   Java native call connectCamDriver()
 * 
 * Connect to O-3000 camera (never returns) until camera is disconnected manually
 * or by application.
 *
 * \param   *env    Pointer to log java env (JVM), automatically generated by jni
 * \param   obj     Pointer to log java object, automaticall generated by jni
 * \param   session Session to use 
 * 
 * \return  ret     succes state
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_connectCamDriver(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint session, jint camNumber){
    int ret, num_camera = -1;

    if(session < 0) {
        printf("%s: camera not initialized\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }

    env_cached = env; // make environment globally available. till termination of programm (JVM)

    // setup color image processing pipeline
    if(color_pipe_open(&color_pipe, IMAGE_FRAME_HEIGHT, IMAGE_FRAME_WIDTH, 12)) {
        printf("%s: Initializing color pipeline failed\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }

    /*
     * Enable various pipeline stages
     * 
     * NOTE: Don't enable any stage because CPU performance is needed. It would be much better
     * if those parameters are set by the user per Java Demo.
     */
//  color_pipe->awb_data.enable = 1;                        // enable white-balancing
//  color_pipe->cam_calib_data.enable = 0;                  // lens correction because lens type is unknown
//  color_pipe->color_calib_data.enable = 1;                // enable color correction
//  color_pipe->color_calib_data.ccm = CCM_PRESET_O3020;    // if color camera is connected, color correction matrix for O-3020 camera is used
//  color_pipe->sharp_data.enable = 0;                      // disable sharpening algrithm because a lot of CPU performance is needed!
// //   color_pipe->sharp_data.sharp_alg = SHARP_ALG_LOCAL;     // local sharpening uses much more CPU performance than global sharpening
//  color_pipe->gamma_data.enable = 0;                      // disable gamma correction

    num_camera = o3000_device_discovery(session);
    if(num_camera < 0) {
        printf("%s: device discovery error (code %d)\n", __func__, num_camera);
        o3000_exit(session);
        return -1;
    }

    if(num_camera == 0) {
//      printf("%s: no camera connected to the system\n", __func__);
        o3000_exit(session);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("%s: Trying %d\n", __func__, currentCam);

    ret = o3000_connect(session, camNumber, xml_msg_default, strlen(xml_msg_default));
        //if(ret == O3000_ERROR_BUSY) {
    if(ret != 0){
        //return ret; -> will return -6
        printf("%s: device %d is already in use\n", __func__, session);
    }

    o3000_exit(session);

    if(color_pipe != NULL) {
        color_pipe_close(color_pipe);
        color_pipe = NULL;
    }

    flag_connection = FALSE;
    return ret;
}

/**
 * \brief   Java native call stopCamDriver()
 * 
 * De-initialises the camera driver and terminates connections
 *
 * \param   *env    Pointer to log java env (JVM), automatically generated by jni
 * \param   obj     Pointer to log java object, automaticall generated by jni
 * \param   session Session to use
 * 
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_o3000_Camo3000JNI_stopCamDriver(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint session){
    o3000_exit(session);
}
```